# Linq - Merging property accessor expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a `MemberExpression` that contains the following: `mail => mail.SomeProperty`.

I want to generate a new member expression to access one level deeper in the hierarchy and have some result like the following: `mail => mail.SomeProperty.OtherProperty`.

How to do this?

Comment: Technically what you have there isn't a `MemberExpression` but a `LambdaExpression`. Or more precisely, `Expression<Func<MailType, SomePropertyType>>` (whatever the types are).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use [Expression.Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348662.aspx) to construct a new MemberExpression that wraps the existing expression with an additional property reference.  It takes an Expression for the first argument, which should be the original MemberExpression.

Comment: I achieved this by using Dynamic Expressions. But actually you can use a Call function on the original expression.